# Interface extends another interface but implements its methods

Tags: java, interface, extends, implements

In java when an interface extends another interface:

1. Why does it implement its methods?
2. How can it implement its methods when an interface can't contain a
   method body
3. How can it implement the methods when it extends the other interface
   and not implement it?
4. What is the purpose of an interface implementing another interface?

This has major concepts in Java!

**EDIT:**

```
public interface FiresDragEvents {

  void addDragHandler(DragHandler handler);

  void removeDragHandler(DragHandler handler);
}


public interface DragController extends FiresDragEvents {

  void addDragHandler(DragHandler handler);

  void removeDragHandler(DragHandler handler);

  void dragEnd();

  void dragMove();
}
```

**In eclipse there is the implement sign besides the implemented methods in `DragController`.**

**And when I mouse-hover it, it says that it implements the method!!!**

Comment: when you extend an interface you can only add to it, this is why you do it. Interfaces don't implement methods.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> Why does it implement its methods? How can it implement its methods
>   when an interface can't contain method body? How can it implement the
>   methods when it extends the other interface and not implement it? What
>   is the purpose of an interface implementing another interface?

Interface does not implement the methods of another interface but just extends them.
One example where the interface extension is needed is: consider that you have a vehicle interface with two methods `moveForward` and `moveBack` but also you need to incorporate the Aircraft which is a vehicle but with some addition methods like `moveUp`, `moveDown` so
in the end you have:

```
public interface IVehicle {
  bool moveForward(int x);
  bool moveBack(int x);
};
```

and airplane:

```
public interface IAirplane extends IVehicle {
  bool moveDown(int x);
  bool moveUp(int x);
};
```

Comment: So, You are basically accumulating methods into one place called `IAirplane` and you actually are not inheriting. Another point is, I would ask the author of `IVehicle` to understand, why this interface `Ivehicle` was not designed to already consider `moveDown()` and `moveBack()`, because `interface` is discovered from existing set of concrete classes(I am assuming airplane concept is available as part of his generation). On the whole, I feel, extending an interface is a consequence of existing bad design, Because we are breaking the purpose of `extends` in this scenario.

Comment: @overexchange no interface in this case is designed before the classes. The interface describes a functionality however the classes represent the real world objects. This is a main difference between the classes and interaces. No regarding moveUp moveDown and so on. Any vehicle can move forward and back however not all of them can move up and down. Aircraft can move forward back and also up and down but different types of aircraft will do it in a different way.

Comment: i did not get you when you said: `interface in this case is designed before the classes.` In any case of any software design, interface is discovered after concrete classes are designed.

Comment: "In any case of any software design, interface is discovered after concrete classes are designed." is not true. Examples COM in c++. In order to implement a new class you have to implement an already existing interface. Java is the same story. Take any OO library and try to extend it, you will have interfaces first...

Comment: extending a library is different from writing a from-scratch application

Comment: Overexchange, are you saying the `IVehicle` interface should have every conceivable method (ie. move up/down/back/forward) as a preferrable design to having an `IAirplane` interface to handle these cases?  Would concrete implementations of cars simply leave these methods unimplemented?

Comment: How about using IVehicle and IAirplane as separate interfaces on one class? As if they were a feature set for the object implementing them? Consider: `interface IVehicle { public function feature_of_IVehicle(); }` and `interface IAirplane { public function feature_of_IAirplane(); }` then `class AB implements IVehicle, IAirplane { ... }`.

Comment: And how now implements all methods? Should I point both interfaces in my Class? I want to implement only `IAirplane` but override 4 methods

Comment: You will need to realize the IAirplane but you would need to implement all the methods as the airplan is considered vehicle in this example. Otherwise you would need to think about a different hierarchy of your interfaces.

Answer (score 23):

An interface defines behavior. For example, a `Vehicle` interface might define the `move()` method.

A Car is a Vehicle, but has additional behavior. For example, the `Car` interface might define the `startEngine()` method. Since a Car is also a Vehicle, the `Car` interface extends the `Vehicle` interface, and thus defines two methods: `move()` (inherited) and `startEngine()`.

The Car interface doesn't have any method implementation. If you create a class (Volkswagen) that implements Car, it will have to provide implementations for all the methods of its interface: `move()` and `startEngine()`.

An interface may not implement any other interface. It can only extend it.

Comment: I have answered them. The 3 first questions don't make sense, since an interface doesn't implement another interface, and doesn't contain any method implementation. The 4th one is answered by my answer: it allows providing additional behavior/methods.

Comment: I would describe it as a small bug of Eclipse. There is no point in redeclaring the methods in the DragController interface, except if you want to provide additional javadoc.

Answer (score 8):

ad 1. It does not implement its methods.

ad 4. The purpose of one interface **extending**, not implementing another, is to build a more specific interface. For example, `SortedMap` is an interface that extends `Map`. A client not interested in the sorting aspect can code against `Map` and handle all the instances of for example `TreeMap`, which implements `SortedMap`. At the same time, another client interested in the sorted aspect can use those same instances through the `SortedMap` interface.

In your example you are repeating the methods from the superinterface. While legal, it's unnecessary and doesn't change anything in the end result. The compiled code will be **exactly the same** whether these methods are there or not. Whatever Eclipse's hover says is irrelevant to the basic truth that *an interface does not implement anything*.